# Custom user meta data

Tags: user-meta

I want to build a WordPress website that redirects the users to a verification page, after successful login on the login page. This verification page should ask for a 6 digit PIN which should be generated every time the user logs in, and destroyed every time the user logs out. Please, how do I go about it?

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.    What have you researched? what code have you tried so far?   I suggest you start by googling two step authentication / verification / login, words like that. See how the answers meet your needs or not, then rephrase your question and describe your observations and conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the documentation for the filter [login_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)

And also see the answer to this [question already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress)

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do with the PIN - is that sent to the user via text/email or displayed on the page?

Either way, the page you redirect to would need to generate the PIN, store it in a (custom) table, then when the user enters the PIN, check the (custom) table on form submission, and then redirect to the page you want them to go after that.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. yeah it will be sent to the user via email. If you create a custom table for the generated pin how would you match it to the user it was generated for inorder to validate it.

Comment: You would also need to store the user id in that table, and probably a column if the PIN is currently active or not (expired or used).
id - unique number; 
pin - number;
userid - number;
active - boolean or number (0 or 1);

this is assuming you create a new row for every pin generated. The other option would be to only have one row per userid and replace the pin when a new one is generated for that user, which would make the 'active' column unnecessary.

Comment: Sorry forgot about you wanting to destroy the pin on logout, so you would just need to delete the row on logout. The 'active' column would be unnecessary also.